# Why is Wordpress' file upload limit so low? Is changing it harmful?

Tags: uploads, php.ini

Why is the WordPress upload limit set to 2mb? This seems prohibitively low, especially when almost everyone has broadband these days.

I know this can be overridden, but I was trying to find a reason it was set to 2mb in the first place, and all I could find was tutorials on how to increase it. What I'm interested in is if there's any reason it *shouldn't* be increased.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, this 2Mb limit is not set by Wordpress, but rather a php default limit set in `php.ini`. As for the specific reason why, I cannot tell you, but my guess would be that it has something to do with webhosting companies.

Before you change any of the defaults like upload size, it is always always a good idea to check with your host and checking what are their requirements regarding a specific issue. You might get your account suspended for not following their policies and rules. Also check your package with them, there is no use having a low bandwitdh, low disk space package and setting your upload size very high. One or two large videos or images can have your account suspended due to going over limit on disk space or bandwidth

Apart from that, it is save to set your limits to your required size

Answer (score 1):

There's no harm increasing file upload size. Now-a-days we all need to increase it as the default is insufficient. Please feel free to increase it. You can also talk with your hosting provider to increase the upload size.

There are many ways to do so.

**Locate theme's function and add below lines:**

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '64M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '64M');
@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' );
```

**In php.ini**

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 300
```

**In htaccess file**

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

Thanks